# Tuck Bootstrap columns under

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I found this problem hard to describe in the title.

I have a `col-md-8` and a `col-md-4` classed div. This provides me a nice sidebar style layout. Therefore when it wraps on a smaller device it will stack. However I have another `col-md-8` div with content that I want to position beneath the other `col-md-8` However beacause bootstrap is the way that it is, it tends to treat it as rows.

View my [codepen mockup](http://codepen.io/moletek/pen/pbGzmY) that I've made. (Basically I want the lower paragraph to meet the top-most paragraph and then be pushed down by my sidebar.) Is this possible? Thanks!

*EDIT* 
I've just made a quick mockup in Balsamiq: Tablet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DoLa.png Mobile: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nguwB.png

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-8 pull-left">content1</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-4 pull-right">sidebar</div>
<div class="col-md-8 pull-left">content2~3</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKbEBQ

Answer (score 1):

You can do this but you need to keep all your content in your col-md-8. Here is the updated Pen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzraOE?editors=1010

And the code change:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <h1>This works amazing on mobile</h1>
    <p>The Museum's rich and varied collections allow us to present money as a fascinating cross-curricular topic. We have consulted widely with teachers and other education professionals to deliver a schools' service which closely supports the Curriculum for Excellence. We hope that you will find it both exciting and relevant!</p>
      <div ><h2>But this is shocking on desktop</h2>
    <p>Children visiting the Museum will engage in hands-on activities based around our extensive collection of original artefacts. These sessions are led by Museum staff and are free of charge. To find out more about the themes we cover, how a school visit is structured, and how to make a booking, please see below.</p>
<p>At present the activities are largely aimed at upper primary pupils (P5-7) and a maximum class size of 33. However, we are happy to adapt them for secondary pupils and visitors with special needs. Please contact us to discuss your requirements.</p>

    <h2>I want to be with the big boys! ^</h2>
    <p>Children visiting the Museum will engage in hands-on activities based around our extensive collection of original artefacts. These sessions are led by Museum staff and are free of charge. To find out more about the themes we cover, how a school visit is structured, and how to make a booking, please see below. 

At present the activities are largely aimed at upper primary pupils (P5-7) and a maximum class size of 33. However, we are happy to adapt them for secondary pupils and visitors with special needs. Please contact us to discuss your requirements.</p>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="well"><h1>Sidebar Content</h1></div>
    <div class="well"><h1>Sidebar Content</h1></div>
        <div class="well"><h1>Sidebar Content</h1></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/a4HYvcXgGA)

Use col-md-push-* and col-md-pull-*

```
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">Top Content</div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">Bottom Content</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Okay you want the paragraphs touching on desktop but the menu between them on mobile.  So using your original code, you can add an id to the bottom col-md-8 and use a custom media query like:

```
@media(min-width:750px){
  #bottom{
    margin-top:-850px
  }
}
```

Updated [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/AOqvshHJJ0)

Comment: This is cool, however I'd like the sidebar images to go beneath the top content but below the bottom content. Sandwiched between text on mobile... But on desktop I want the paragraph together and the image on the side

Comment: @JonahMcLachlan must have misunderstood your meaning.  That i'm not sure is possible with bootstrap alone.

Comment: thanks for this, in a way it does solve it! But look: https://i.imgur.com/sgi8q2c.png Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @JonahMcLachlan have u seen my approuch? 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38920923/5139079

Comment: @JonahMcLachlan Pedro's is probably the best way to actually do this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but is there a reason you've separated out your second block of text? If you remove your second col-md-8 and just add that text to the first, it will stack in mobile while not creating the white space in desktop view:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-8">all text...</div>
<div class="col-md-4">side bar</div>
</div>
```

[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/tadamo/pen/YWBzOv)

Comment: Hi there I want 
`<h1>`
`<sidebar>`
`<h2` for mobile

Answer (score 0):

You have to put all text in col-md-8, then all sidebar in col-md4

co the col-md-8 will be the parent for the "left" side - and in this can be another col-md-8, and the col-md-4 will be parent for sidebar and ther could be another col-md-4 but it isnt necessary

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <h1>This works amazing on mobile</h1>
    <p>The Museum's rich and varied collections allow us to present money as a fascinating cross-curricular topic. We have consulted widely with teachers and other education professionals to deliver a schools' service which closely supports the Curriculum for Excellence. We hope that you will find it both exciting and relevant!</p>
  </div> 
  <div class="col-md-8"><h2>But this is shocking on desktop</h2>
    <p>Children visiting the Museum will engage in hands-on activities based around our extensive collection of original artefacts. These sessions are led by Museum staff and are free of charge. To find out more about the themes we cover, how a school visit is structured, and how to make a booking, please see below.</p>
<p>At present the activities are largely aimed at upper primary pupils (P5-7) and a maximum class size of 33. However, we are happy to adapt them for secondary pupils and visitors with special needs. Please contact us to discuss your requirements.</p>

    <h2>I want to be with the big boys! ^</h2>
    <p>Children visiting the Museum will engage in hands-on activities based around our extensive collection of original artefacts. These sessions are led by Museum staff and are free of charge. To find out more about the themes we cover, how a school visit is structured, and how to make a booking, please see below. 

At present the activities are largely aimed at upper primary pupils (P5-7) and a maximum class size of 33. However, we are happy to adapt them for secondary pupils and visitors with special needs. Please contact us to discuss your requirements.</p>
</div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="well"><h1>Sidebar Content</h1></div>
    <div class="well"><h1>Sidebar Content</h1></div>
        <div class="well"><h1>Sidebar Content</h1></div>
  </div>
</div>
```